# Anchor: Signing and paying for transactions to interact with program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, wallet, solana-wallet-adapter

How can I make anchor wallet pay and/or sign transactions for interacting with a program?
Here is the block of code:

```
const createMerchantAccount = await this.program.methods
  .createMerchant()
  .accounts({
    user: this.userPubKey,
    merchantAccount: merchantPDA,
  })
  .signers([this.anchorWallet.signTransaction()]) // what do I put here?
  .rpc();
```

I had someone say that I should use this as the signer and just to pay for transactions, but it didn't work:

```
readonly anchorWallet: AnchorWallet,
readonly userKeypair = (anchorWallet as NodeWallet).payer,
```

Should I be using solana's useWallet() instead?
Any response would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's in the browser, use:

```
const transaction = await this.program.methods
  .createMerchant()
  .accounts({
    user: this.userPubKey,
    merchantAccount: merchantPDA,
  })
  .transaction()
```

And set `recentBlockHash` and `feePayer` on the `transaction`.
Then sent it via to be processed.